# How to put round cornered frame around an image

Tags: graphics, mdframed, rounded-corners

I want a nice colored frame around an image which has rounded corners. Here is my attempt, using **mdframed**, but, as you can see, the inner edge of the frame is a right-angle, and not rounded. I would like the inner edge of the frame to overlay (chop off) the corners of the image to produce a rounded inner edge. Is there a nice easy way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

\parindent=0pt
\baselineskip=0pt
\parskip=0pt


\def\myimage{c:/images/donald.png}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=5pt, leftmargin=2cm,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt, innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt, innerlinewidth=0pt, middlelinewidth=0pt,outerlinewidth=10pt, outerlinecolor=red]% 
\hsize=5cm\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{\myimage}
\end{mdframed}% 

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: If, instead of `\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=5cm]{\myimage}` you put there something like `TEXT`, you'll see the round inner corners. This shows that angles are produced by your image: it overlaps the frame. Just increase the inner margins to see your beautiful frame.

Comment: The problem caused of the output-routine. First the frame will drawn and then the contents.

Comment: This is correct, but I'd argue this is a feature rather than a bug.  I would not want my frames to overlap my contents.  Maybe this calls for a variant of `mdframed` called, say, `matte`, which is drawn over the contents.

Comment: @Boris: thanks but increasing the inner margins reveals an inner border which I do not want (the graphic will not necessarily have a white background). How can I force the frame to overwrite the image?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks,graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox

\begin{document}    
\leavevmode
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{/tmp/donald}}
\put(0,0){\usebox\IBox}%
\psframe[framearc=0.2,framesep=0pt, cornersize=relative,
  linecolor=blue,linewidth=3mm](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same with clipping theimage:

```
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{/tmp/donald.png}}
\begin{pspicture}(\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\psclip{\psframe[framearc=0.7,linestyle=none](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)}
\rput[lb](0,0){\usebox\IBox}%
\endpsclip
\psframe[framearc=0.7,framesep=0pt, cornersize=relative,
  linecolor=blue,linewidth=4mm](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but if in your solution you change to "framesep=0pt" then you get the same problem. I do not want another border inside the outer frame.

Comment: @Dan: that is also no problem.

Comment: this looks good...and I can almost understand it! :-)

Comment: as the radius increases (say framearc=0.7), then the image edges protrude outside the borders: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FSaRV.png. Is there a way of clipping it?

Comment: @Dan: Please don't edit answers with follow-up questions or comments. You can add links to uploaded images in the comments as well. Simply upload it using a post which you then discard and copy the link.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I couldn't work out how to add an image to a comment, now I know, thanks.

Comment: @Dan: see first comment :-) "that is also no problem, I edited the answer

Comment: @Herbert: that looks great, but when I run it I get the following error (any idea why?):
** WARNING ** Error while parsing PDF file.
** WARNING ** Failed to parse the clipping path.
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PST: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(152.033, 609.492)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "PST:  tx@Dict begin /mtrxc CM def CP CP T STV newpath /ArrowA {"

Comment: @Dan: Did you run it with `xelatex`?

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, XeLaTex (MikTex 2.8)

Comment: @Dan: I suppose an old xdvipdfmx driver. Can you update to MiKTeX 2.9?

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, installing MikTeX 2.9 fixed the problem. Your solution is much faster than the TikZ solution by Marco, and easier to understand, thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to create rounded corners without boarder line with this solution?

Answer (score 19):

As Martin mentioned in the comment and I think `mdframed` is to break a butterfly on a wheel, I want to present a tikz-Solution:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newsavebox\MyPicture
%\roundedpicture[graphcis-setup][tikz-setup]{graphics path}
\NewDocumentCommand{\roundedpicture}%
      {O{width=0.6\linewidth}
       O{draw=blue,line width=6pt,rounded corners=5pt}
       m}{%
   \savebox\MyPicture{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
   \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw [path picture={%
                   \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {%
                       \usebox\MyPicture};},#2]
          (0,0)  rectangle (\wd\MyPicture,\ht\MyPicture);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\roundedpicture[width=5cm]{donald-duck}

\roundedpicture{donald-duck}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### ORIGINAL POST uses mdframed

You can change the behavior of the background. By default it is drawn as a filled rectangle.

With the following code you put a dummy in the environment to get the picture in the foreground.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{short}{roundcorner=5pt, leftmargin=2cm,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt, innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt, innerlinewidth=0pt, middlelinewidth=0pt,outerlinewidth=10pt, outerlinecolor=red}


\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd\addtikzsetting[1]{%
   \appto\md@tikz@settings{#1}%
}

\addtikzsetting{%
   \tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={path picture={
                     \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {%
                       \includegraphics[height=5cm,width=5cm]{donald-duck}
             };}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=short,]
\hsize=5cm\rule{0pt}{5cm}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

<sub>I think `mdframed` isn't the correct environment. You should create you own environment via tikz.</sub>

Now the modification with a new command so that it can be centered or whatever you want.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{short}{roundcorner=10pt,innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt, innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt, innerlinewidth=0pt, middlelinewidth=0pt,middlelinewidth=10pt, middlelinecolor=red,leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt}


\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\MyPicture
%\roundedpicture[mdframed-setup][graphic-setup]{graphics-name}
\NewDocumentCommand{\roundedpicture}{o o m}{%
  \savebox\MyPicture{\includegraphics[#2]{#3}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\wd\MyPicture+20pt\relax}
  \appto\md@tikz@settings{%
     \tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={path picture={%
         \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[#2]{#3}};}%
          }%
      }%
   }%
  \begin{mdframed}[style=short,#1,nobreak]
    \hsize=\dimexpr\wd\MyPicture\relax%
     \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht\MyPicture+\dp\MyPicture\relax}
      \rule{\dimexpr\wd\MyPicture\relax}{0pt}
   \end{mdframed}%
   \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
\roundedpicture[][width=3cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{donald-duck}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works beautifully (I think)...now I have to study it to find out how it works! :-)

Comment: @Dan: Can you mark this question as answered.

Comment: is it possible to mark 2 answers? It looks like Herbert's answer is also correct, as well as yours.

Comment: @Dan: No. You must decide ;-).

Comment: Why not use TikZ directly in this case? It's much simpler IMHO.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I know. I think it is "Mit Kanonen auf Spatzen schießen" I don't know the English meaning. Please note my sententce *I think mdframed isn't the correct environment. You should create you own environment via tikz.* -- I will create an example with tikz.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I edited my post.

Comment: @Marco Daniel: Do me a favour and decrease the size of the images ...

Comment: @Marco: this is a very elegant solution, but it runs much slower than the PsTricks solution provided by Herbert. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Dan: Of course. pstricks uses the external language postscript and tikz uses the latex-macros. That's the reason why pstricks is more efficient for complex arithmetic.

Comment: Really like this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tcbincludegraphics` command from `tcolorbox`.
The first example show default settings (and image's original sharp corners) , the second fixes box (with frame) width and third shows how to define `graphics` options and keep adjusted border. As can be seen image corners are rounded in second and third examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
    myframe/.style={
        colframe=red,
        boxrule=1mm,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt
        }
}

\begin{document}

\tcbincludegraphics[width=5cm]{frog}

\tcbincludegraphics[myframe, width=5cm]{frog}

\tcbincludegraphics[myframe, hbox, graphics options={width=7cm, viewport=120 300 646 500, clip}]{frog}

\end{document}
```

[image]